# Use of doxygen's \link command

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

I have an external HTML file I'd like to have linked form either my doxygen "Related Pages" tab or the left hand frame. It seems I need to use the `\link` command but I can't find a good example of how to use it or where. I am currently using doxywizard to generate the HTML.

So, is `\link` something I incorporate into my doxygen config file or do I add it when I build the HTML somehow?

**Update**

So I ended up having to do the following:

1. Create a new page (docs_main.html) that had the following:

   ```
   /*! \mainpage MY TITLE HERE
    * \section intro_sec External resources
    * <a href="link_to_my_external_page.html">My external page</a>
    */
   ```
2. Include that page in my doxygen included files list
3. Rebuild my documentation

That added to my doxygen "Main Page" the following

```
MY TITLE HERE

My external page (which was a link to that page)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Doxygen allows you to insert [certain HTML commands](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/htmlcmds.html) in to your documentation, including links.  In case you didn't know this is how you make a link in HTML:

```
<a href="externalfile.html">External file</a>
```

[cdiggins' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154848/looking-for-how-to-use-doxygen-link/6171650#6171650) is also worth reading.

Answer (score 19):

We have a **Markdown support** in doxygen nowadays. Your code may be a clearer:

```
/*! \mainpage MY TITLE HERE
 * \anchor intro_sec
 * # External resources
 * [My external page](http://link_to_my_external_page.html)
 */
```

The above should render somewhat close to:

---

## External resources

[My external page](http://link_to_my_external_page.html)

---

Answer (score 4):

The \link (and anything of the form \command or @command) is called a "special command" and is part of the mark-up used in the input files processed by Doxygen not part of the configuration. The [\link command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdlink) does not do what you want.

You could perhaps use the [\page command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdpage) to create a new related page and then use the [\htmlinclude command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdhtmlinclude) to insert the external HTML file as the contents of that page.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers here looks bits and pieces for a beginner, here is the complete procedure.

1) create an html file with content(ex:abc.html) as below

```
/*! \mainpage MY TITLE HERE 
 * \section intro_sec External resources
 * <a href="link_to_my_external_page.html">My external page</a>
 */
```

2) Add this file path in config file here

     `INPUT =`

3)Also add your file type here 

     `FILE_PATTERNS  =`

The above procedure opens your file in doxygen window

Add the below content to open the file in explorer

`<a href="link_to_my_external_page.html" target="_blank"><b>My external page</b></a>`

Note: If file doesn't open try giving absolute path

Answer (score 0):

You can add a tab to the main navigation bar (with your link) by using a custom layout file.

Take a look at the [Customizing the Output](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout) page of the Doxygen manual.  It's pretty clear about how to do it, assuming I understood your question.