# How to add an external resource (pdf file) in my doxygen documentation

Tags: doxygen

I generate a doxygen documentation. In one of my "page" I have a link to a pdf file:

```
<a href="../documents/xxx.pdf" target="_blank"><b>Overview</b></a>
```

This file is in my project in another directory. The documentation ends up in folder called "html".

How do I tell doxygen to copy the pdf file into html ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a doxygen configuration option `HTML_EXTRA_FILES` that allows extra files to be copied to the root of the html documentation. You should be able to specify the following to copy the file:

```
HTML_EXTRA_FILES = ../documents/xxx.pdf
```

This will place xxx.pdf in the root of your HTML documentation, so you will likely need to change your link to:

```
<a href="xxx.pdf" target="_blank"><b>Overview</b></a>
```

Comment: What about if the pdf is somewhere online?

Comment: @Danijel your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154848/use-of-doxygens-link-command