# doxygen how to hyperlink to related page

Tags: doxygen

I am new to doxygen and i could not find the syntax for me to create a link from main page to a specific page in the related pages section.

For example , i am looking for something similar to this :

http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/index.html

fox example:

PortAudio API Overview  -> This is a link to related page.

A top-down view of the PortAudio API, its capabilities, functions and data structure

Any ideas how can i do that ?

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 12):

This should work with `\ref`

```
//! \page handle MyPage
//! text in MyPage

//! Some variable. For additional information look at \ref handle "this cool page"
int myvar;
```

Comment: And to link the main page, use `\ref index "Link to the main page"`

Comment: Link to related pages can be achieved (in `\htmlonly`) as `<a href="pages.html">Related Pages</a>`. Though this is likely a bit fragile, it seems to be the only way to link that right now.

Comment: @theswine This is not true. It can be easely done by `[Related Pages](pages.html)` and also e.g. `[Related Page](https://exmaple.com)`. Same can also be used in combination with e.g. `\ref` and `\subpage` like `[Related internal Page](\ref someLable)`

Comment: Rather nicely, `\ref handle` on its own will use the title of the target page as the displayed name.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- link to an external `html` you created:

  `/*! \mainpage MY TITLE HERE`

  `* \section intro_sec External resources`

  `* <a href="link_to_my_external_page.html">My external page</a>`

  `*/`

  see also [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154848/use-of-doxygens-link-command).
- link to an URL or e-mail:

  `<http://www.example.com>`

  `<https://www.example.com>`

  `<ftp://www.example.com>`

  `<mailto:address@example.com>`

  `<address@example.com>`

  see also the [documentation of doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_autolink).

PS. Go to the example you provided and let your browser show you the code of the page. This might help you to understand basic principles of syntax.

Comment: He wants to do an internal link, not an external link!