# Doxygen Link to page

Tags: hyperlink, doxygen

I want to create a link to a page in the documentation.

I am currently using

```
///  You will find a copy here. 
///
///  \ref clicn
```

I want the link to be `here` rather than the name of the page 
that `clicn` refers to.

Comment: Not completely sure what you want, but from the documentation: \ref <name> [”(text)”] so I think it might be \ref clicn "here"

Answer (score 0):

This should work with `\ref`

```
//! \page handle MyPage
//! text in MyPage

//! Some variable. For additional information look at \ref handle "this cool page"
int myvar;
```

This is also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29652385/4675668)